# iOS6 multithreading with CLLocationManager (how not to delay main thread)

Tags: ios, multithreading, cllocationmanager

I have a question about multithreading in iOS6.
I make app, that starts and stops CLLocationManager, when user press the UISwitch. 
I start CLLocationManager in separate thread (I don't want user seen any delay in main thread) , but sometimes UISwitch didn't change it's value. Delay occurs. I think it is because of starting CLLocationManager. Why it happens? I thought, that if I use threading, there will be no delay in main thread.
The code:

```
- (IBAction)useGPS:(UISwitch *)sender {
if (![trackLocationSwitch isOn]) {
    [useGPSSwitch setOn:NO];
    return;
}
if ([sender isOn]) {
    [accuracyLabel setText:@"Satellite"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        [trackLocation startTrackLocationUsingOnlyGPS:YES];
    });
} else {
    [accuracyLabel setText:@"Cellular"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        [trackLocation stopTrackLocation];
        [trackLocation startTrackLocationUsingOnlyGPS:NO];
    });
}
```

TrackLocation.m:

```
- (void)startTrackLocationUsingOnlyGPS:(BOOL)useOnlyGPS {
if ( useOnlyGPS ) {
    [self restartLocationManagerWithBestAccuracy:YES];
    useBestAccuracy = YES;
    onlyGPS = YES;
} else {
    [self restartLocationManagerWithBestAccuracy:NO];
    useBestAccuracy = NO;
    onlyGPS = NO;
}

- (void)stopTrackLocation {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}

- (void)restartLocationManagerWithBestAccuracy:(BOOL)_useBestAccuracy {
    if ( _useBestAccuracy ) {
        useBestAccuracy = YES;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager setPausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically:NO];
        [locationManager setActivityType:CLActivityTypeFitness];
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:100];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    } else {
        useBestAccuracy = NO;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use queues here. You don't need it to call  startUpdatingLocation.

Comment: Why? Because it is an asynchronous operation?

Comment: When you call startUpdatingLocation, the location manager will start updating location and send messages to its delegate when it has an update. It does not lag the UI. If you want to know where your app is spending time, I suggest you use the Instruments tool provided with Xcode, specially the time profile option.

Comment: Thanks, @Thedude. I tried to use Instruments tool and figured out, that most of the time spends for locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method. And it executes in main thread. I wrapped this method in another thread and it seems, that delay problem disappeared. Thanks!